# ActionScript 3 startDrag with Rectangle area

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie clip called site plan (which is an image of a site plan) and I have zoom gestures in place to to zoom in and those are working well. Now I want to put MouseEvents in place to do dragging when the movie clip is is zoomed in.  I seem to having trouble with setting the Rectangle area x and y axis. What I am to do is make the movie clip dragged inside the 1080 x 1420 area and have the following when zoomed in

- Bottom of the image is at the bottom of the rectangle area stop dragging
- Top of the image is at the top of the rectangle area stop dragging
- Left side of the image is at the left of the rectangle area stop dragging
- Right side of the image is at the right of the rectangle area stop dragging.

My code is below. The size of my image is 1080 x 1420 and my stage is 1080 * 1920

```
siteplan.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragStart);
siteplan.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragEnd);

function dragStart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0 - 1080, 0 - 1920, 1080, 1420);
    siteplan.startDrag(false, rect); 
}

function dragEnd(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    siteplan.stopDrag();
}
```

I hope this make sense, Please Help!

I have also tried:

```
function dragStart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0 - (1080 * e.currentTarget.x), 0 - (1920 * e.currentTarget.y), 1080, 1420);
    siteplan.startDrag(false, rect); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event listeners you're looking at will only fire once, which (while a good start) doesn't actually allow for dragging.  Also, with the current design, you're creating a new `Rectangle` object every time you `mouseDown`.

The crux of your issue depends on clamping the siteplan to your screen.  I've written such a function below, along with a demonstration of your project functioning as you described.  Note that you can compile this in a clean project, and using your scrollwheel to zoom, and mouse drag to pan, the map stays within the bounds of your screen.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;

var cursor:Object = { // tracks the starting coordinates
    "drag":false // whether we're currently dragging.
}

// Load our test "map"
var map:Loader = new Loader();
map.load(new URLRequest("http://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Fallout-4-Map.png"));
addChild(map)

// Event Listeners
map.addEventListener("mouseDown", drag);
map.addEventListener("mouseMove", drag);
map.addEventListener("mouseUp", drag);
map.addEventListener("releaseOutside", drag);
map.addEventListener("mouseWheel", zoom);

function zoom(e:MouseEvent):void {
    // Using the scrollwheel, we'll zoom in (up to 3x) or out (down to stage size)
    var increment:Number = 1.2;
    if (e.delta < 0) { increment = 0.8; }

    map.width = clamp(map.width * increment, this.loaderInfo.width, map.width/map.scaleX * 3);
    map.height = clamp(map.height * increment, this.loaderInfo.height, map.height/map.scaleY * 3);
    map.scaleY = map.scaleX;
    map.x =  - (mouseX/this.loaderInfo.width) * (map.width - this.loaderInfo.width);
    map.y =  - (mouseY/this.loaderInfo.height) * (map.height - this.loaderInfo.height);
}

function drag(e:Event):void {
    switch (e.type) {
        case "mouseDown":
            // Store the starting points for both cursor and map.
            cursor.x = map.x - mouseX;
            cursor.y = map.y - mouseY;
            cursor.drag = true;
            break;
        case "mouseMove":
            // When moving the mouse, if we're technically dragging...
            if (cursor.drag) {
                // Offset the current location by the delta of the cursor and the original position of the map.
                map.x = clamp(mouseX + cursor.x, -map.width + this.loaderInfo.width, 0);
                map.y = clamp(mouseY + cursor.y, -map.height + this.loaderInfo.height, 0);
            }           
            break;
        case "mouseUp":
        case "releaseOutside":
            cursor.drag = false;
            break;
    }
}

function clamp(original:Number, low:Number, high:Number):Number {
    return (original > high) ? high : (original < low) ? low : original;
}
```